# SQLAlchemy, select such A that has at least one B with raised flag

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

I have two tables:

```
class A(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class B(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
    a = relationship(A)
    flag = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

As you can see - each object from B is related to one object from A, also, more that one object from B can be related to single object from A.

I need to select all A's that have AT LEAST one related B with flag == False.

For now I'm thinking on something like this:

```
    selection = session.query(A).\
        join(B).\
        filter(
            B.a_id == A.id,
            B.flag == False,
        ).\
        group_by(A)
```

But I'm not sure about two things:

1. If this query is correct? (I'm working with huge amounts of data and it's quite complicated to test this out).
2. If this query is correct from point of sqlalchemy philosophy? (I'm newbie with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `backref` to the relationship:

```
class B(Base):
    # ...
    a = relationship(A, backref="b_s")
```

Then the `sqlalchemy` verino of @Erwin's `SQL` version is below:

```
qry = session.query(A).filter(A.b_s.any(B.flag == False))
```

If you do not want or cannot add the `backref` to the relationship, the below will produce the same query for simple case, but you should keep an eye on generated `SQL` in case you have more complicated queries as the joins might need more tweaking:

```
qry = (session.query(A).filter(
    exists(select([1]).where(B.a_id == A.id).where(B.flag == False)))
)
```

Comment: is it possible without backref?

Answer (score 1):

A fitting query would be with an [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE a_id = A.id AND flag = FALSE);
```

For this to be fast you should have *any* index on `B` with `a_id` as only or first expression. If this queries with the condition `flag = FALSE` are common, consider a **partial index** like:

```
CREATE INDEX b_some_nmae_idx ON b(a_id) WHERE flag = FALSE;
```

Joining to *all* matching rows in `B` and aggregating again (like you have in the question) is a lot of pointless work. `EXISTS` can stop as soon as the first matching row in `B` is found.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually, I know how to do it in raw SQL :) I need to do the same using sqlalchemy.

Comment: @sennoy: As I added to my answer: the query you have now is not the best choice in *SQL*.